# add additional data to geojson with leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm using leaflet to create a world map with geojson. Now I need to add some additional information as popup for each country but I'm not sure how should I proceed it. Been finding solution for hours.

1. Should I modify geojson file to add 1 more field since it already listed coordinates of all the countries. Can I achieve this by php or js?
2. Should I just store the information in SQL ("US" -> "US's text", "Canada" -> "Canada's text,...) & use switch case to compare string in **onEachFeature** function?

Comment: Easy way to add field, is open the GeoJSON file at http://geojson.io and add a field, You can even add values there and save the file. Then in Leaflet onEachFeature, just bindpopup to feature.properties.MyNewField.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using QGIS to build your Leafletjs or OpenLayers map
You install the QGIS2Web Plugin and run through the wizard https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/wiki

Then you have a fully functional map. You can then tweak the generated code. It even generates the styling and labeling! Very powerful and free.